# Click change color

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I am working on a website and I want that when the user clicks on a specific card, it turns blue. I have searched and found some things online, but it is not working for me and I don't know why;
here is the code:

```
<div class="card" onclick="myFunction()">
  <p class="number-card">1</p>
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("card").style.backgroundcolor = "blue";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Typo. Should be `backgroundColor `

Comment: You don't have an element with id of `card`.

Comment: Also don't use `onclick` Use addeventListener instead

Comment: Also, you're missing that you use Classes, not IDs. Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementById` - and if you have more cards, use a `.forEach` to assign event listeners to every element.

Comment: how do I use .forEach?

Answer (score 3):

- You're missing an ID - anyways, use Classes instead with `document.querySelectorAll(".card")` [MDN querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- Should be `backgroundColor` with capital `C`
- Use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline JS `on*` attribute handlers. JS and styles should always be in their respective tags or files, not disseminated around a HTML file.
- Read about [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

```html
<div class="card">
  <p class="number-card">1</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p class="number-card">2</p>
</div>

<script>
  const changeBgColor = (ev) => {
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  };
  const EL_cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  EL_cards.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", changeBgColor));
</script>
```

Alternatively, using a regular function (where addEventListener binds by default `this` to the `Event.currentTarget` Element):

```
function changeBgColor() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: `.eventTarget` is only relevant because of the arrow function (which is not necessary or in any way helpful, because it "blocks" the `this`). Without it `this` would be the `.card` and therefor you could use `this.style.backgroundColor = ...`

Comment: @Andreas as it was in my previous edit. I changed it to Arrow function on purpose.

Comment: Then please mention that "purpose" so OP and future readers can work with it. Otherwise your answer just introduces an unmentioned and (imho) unnecessary change which as a result requires another concept to make it work.

Comment: @Andreas ... it's all in the answer - just take a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

You only have the class set to card but you're trying to getElementById, you should give the div an id that's unique and change the function.

Comment: Thanks, I am new in js, I thought the class was the id :)